# Problems using ftp to upload JSON file with python

Tags: python, ftp

I need some help please with using FTP to upload a JSON file, I've tried to read up on a solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

My code looks as follows:

```
ftp = FTP('xxx.xxx.x.xx','Uname','Pword')
ftp.cwd("/incoming")
file=open('C:/MyFile.json', 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR MyFile.json','file')
```

When I run this, I get an error saying:

```
line 505, in storbinary
buf = fp.read(blocksize)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Pass `file`, not `'file'`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ftp.storbinary` expects an open file-like object, not a string. You should pass `file` instead of `'file'` (which I assume is more of a typo).